# Skype still receiving calls after terminating process

Tags: windows-10, process, skype, services

Skype on Windows 10 will still receive incoming calls even after terminating the process. There are no services to disable under the names 'Skype' or 'Microsoft Skype'. How can I prevent Skype from receiving calls/communicating with their server after I manually exit the application and terminate the process. I would prefer not to sign out of the app each time.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to make clear what you mean when you say that you are terminating the process.
For instance, if you close the app by clicking on the X top-right and have *not* deselected the Skype setting 'On Close - Keep Skype Running' then you have in reality only minimized Skype. It is still running.

You see, like a good MS implemented app Skype does not voluntarily let go :-)
Even after making the above selection there's two remaining processes that 'like to stick around';

Runtime Broker (RuntimeBroker.exe) and
Microsoft Skype (SkypeHost.exe)

You can see these with Task Manager.

If you have 'terminated' all of those and still are receiving calls then we're on 'a new level'.

Answer (score 0):

If we do not want Skype receives any message, first we need to make sure that Skype is no longer running.

The quickest way to close Skype is to right-click the Skype icon displayed in the system tray at the bottom right of the screen and select Exit.

[image]

To make sure that Skype is no longer running, check that all Skype processes have been closed:
[image]

1. Press CTRL+ALT+DELETE.
2. Click Task Manager.
3. In the Processes tab, search for any entry beginning with the word "Skype".
4. Highlight the entry beginning with "Skype" and click End Task.
5. Click Yes to end the process.
6. Repeat until all Skype processes have been closed.

Comment: As my question states, I am exiting out of Skype and terminating all the processes in Task Manager. The only thing I am not doing is Signing Out before terminating the process.